# API Design for sub resources?

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm building quite a complex web API but something that I am a bit confused about is the creation of sub resources.

Specifically, think in terms of games,

A game belongs to a round, a round to a season, a season to a competition.
Outside of it's parent context each item has no relevance but they are resources regardless.

So I wonder what my url pattern should be to create a game?

```
//full tree map
PUT /competitions/1/seasons/2/rounds/3/games

//each sub resource has it's own top level, but must be created under 
//it's parent
PUT /rounds/3/games 

//each sub resource has it's own top level, and we include the parent 
//id in the resource body.
PUT /games
```

I would prefer to have /games as it's own top level as it goes deeper, for example, a game has a statistic, and a statistic has a video so doing the full tree map could get quite heavy to handle, perhaps I should support all three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical pattern would be to make the top level the canonical URI for the resource, but allow GETs off of the full tree. So:

```
GET /competitions/1/seasons/2/rounds/3/games

GET /games
GET /games/12
PUT /games
    competition=1
    season=2
    round=3
```

There's a slightly greater support burden for you doing this. Are you sure it's worth it?

```
GET /games?competition=1&season=2&round=3
```

is also reasonable. I would expect that part of the response of the competitions resource would be a list URIs to the seasons in that competition.

I would suggest not having multiple URIs which support PUTs, POSTs, PATCHes, or DELETEs. Your code will quickly become a headache to support.